# Cocoa NSInteger when building in 64bit architecture

Tags: cocoa, nsinteger

I have an NSSegmentedControl set up as a sender, adding functions when the user clicks through each button in the object. The snippet below always worked fine for me. It still does, however I'm getting the following warning when I build using 64bit architecture. The warning goes away when I revert to 32 bit. Can someone please advise me on how to edit the code?
Thanks for the help. -paul.

"implicit conversion loses integer precision: NSInteger (aka long) to "int"

```
int selectedSegment = [arSegController selectedSegment];
int clickedSegmentTag = [[arSegController cell] tagForSegment:selectedSegment];

if (clickedSegmentTag == 0) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `NSInteger` instead of `int` for your variables.  You can just look at the declarations in `NSSegmentedControl.h`, but better is to read Apple's [64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html).

Comment: Thanks allot. Got it sorted out ... -paul.

Comment: Sure, happy to help. Please click on the check mark to the left of my answer to mark it as "accepted"; accepting answers will help you get more answers in future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An NSInteger is nothing more than a typedef'd long.  You should be using NSInteger but if for some reason you NEED to use int then try typecasting.

```
int selectedSegment = (int)[arSegController selectedSegment];
```

Answer (score 1):

[64 bit guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/transition/transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001064-CH207-SW1)

I believe you are assigning a long variable of 8 bytes long to a an int that is 4 bytes long. I think in mac they use LP64 which means longs and pointers get 8 bytes. declaring selectedSegment NSInteger as well should remedy the problem. On 32 bit machines long would be 32 bits, while on 64 bit machines it would be 64 bits.

```
NSInteger selectedSegment = [arSegController selectedSegment]; 
NSInteger clickedSegmentTag = [[arSegController cell] tagForSegment:selectedSegment]; 

if (clickedSegmentTag == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

NSInteger seems to be defined to long on 64-bit platforms (so on 32-bit OS X and iOS you won't get this warning). Also, on these platforms, long is 64 bits long, while int is 32 bit only - so, as the compiler tells you, you loose precision. Numbers >= 2 ^ 32 cannot be represented in 32 bit, so for these numbers, you would likely experience some odd behavior (related to the numbers getting truncated).

Solution: explicitly cast the return value of the method to `(int)`.